# TypeScript error regarding uninitialized variables in class constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript is complaining about an uninitialized class property, even though it appears to be properly assigned.

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```js
type Config = {
    color: string;
}

class Toto {
    color: string;

    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.setConfig(config);
    }

    setConfig(config: Config) {
        this.color = config.color;
    }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAYzgBs4AnALigGdhKUE0BuPAXzz2LIEM6dKABU4wOLgJFSFGvUbM23IiUQNKAV2LjKAClLJ0teIbQBKSSpXAAFijoA6OhGAnUafYndn2KrlMJnVy90T1NjEPNLK0JbewcZKixVUwTyKl8iLg4gA)

The compiler underlines the `color` property definition and throws the following error:

> Property 'color' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

The issue appears to be with using the `setConfig` method to set the value of `color`, since the following code produces no compiler errors:

```js
type Config = {
    color: string;
}

class Toto {
    color: string;

    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.color = config.color;
    }
}
```

This problem is I want to be able to use the `setConfig` method to set class properties to different values during the lifetime of a class instance. I don't want to have to repeated the same code within both my constructor and `setConfig` method just to get around a TS compiler issue.

Does anyone know why the compiler can't see that the class variable is properly being set in the constructor?

Comment: What you're describing isn't allowed in TypeScript because `setConfig` could be overridden in a subclass and that override could choose to not set `this.color`. The only way TypeScript can guarantee that `this.color` is set is by requiring it to be set directly in the constructor.

Comment: You can always initialise it to `null` or empty string or a similar default value.

Comment: Ah, so you could subclass `Toto` and overide it with a different `setConfig` method and then that new method would be used by the `Toto` class constructor? @Dai

Comment: @RobertCooper Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you as the developer are certain that `color` will not go uninitialized in the constructor you can just tell the compiler that this is the case:

```
type Config = {
    color: string;
}

class Toto {
    color!: string;

    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.setConfig(config);
    }

    setConfig(config: Config) {
        this.color = config.color;
    }
}
```

The `!` tells the compiler that this variable will not be null at the point when `!` is used.

Of course in an ideal world the compiler would be able to detect the indirect setting but I don't think this is currently possible.

[Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAYzgBs4AnALigGdhKUE0BuPAXzz2LIEM6dKABU4wOLgJFSFSgEJaDJi3ZTCpBEoCuxcZQAUG1Glrxk6AJSSiNqMAAWKOgDo6EYGeOHExi+xtcavTunuje5iawPpbWtoQOTs4yVFgk0WhJ5FT+RFwcQA)

Comment: Oh sweet, I did not know about the `!` technique!

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript does not allow this since the `setConfig` method could be overwritten if even the `Toto` class is subclassed:

```
class SubToto extends Toto {
    setConfig() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Therefore, the two possible approaches are:

1. Set the values directly in the constructor, and repeat the code within `setConfig`:

```
class Toto {
    color: string;

    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.color = config.color;
    }

    setConfig(config: Config) {
        this.color = config.color;
    }
}
```

This has the downside of repeating the code.

2. Setting an initial empty value to the property.

```
class Toto {
    color: string | null = null;

    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.setConfig(config)
    }

    setConfig(config: Config) {
        this.color = config.color;
    }
}
```

This has the downside of having to now check if the property is empty before using it elsewhere in your class methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, because initially color is undefined. Or initialise it to empty string like `private color: string = '';`.

```
type Config = {
    color: string;
}

class Toto {

    private color: string|undefined;
    
    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.setConfig(config);
    }

    setConfig(config: Config) {
        this.color = config.color;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `private color: string | null = null;` is better than using `undefined`, imo.

Comment: Ya, I was hoping to avoid having to set an initial empty value, but it appears as though it might be the best workaround.